# fetch response.json() and response.status

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

Is this the only way to use the [body.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json) and also get the status code?

```
let status;

return fetch(url)
    .then((response => {
         status = response.status;
         return response.json()
     })
    .then(response => {
        return {
            response: response,
            status: status
        }
    });
```

This doesn't work as it returns a promise in the response field:

```
.then((response)=> {return {response: response.json(), status: response.status}})
```

Comment: What is wrong with *return {'response': resp.json(), 'status': resp.status}* ?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle `response` will contain the promise that `.json()` returns, rather than the parsed payload of the response.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Your status is not visible in the second `then`. You can just get the two properties in the single `then`.

`json()` returns a new Promise to you, so you need to create your object inside the `then` of the result of that function. If you return a Promise from a function, it will be fulfilled and will return the result of the fulfillment - in our case the object.

```js
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
.then(r =>  r.json().then(data => ({status: r.status, body: data})))
.then(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: `response.body` is a ReadableStream. `response.json` is a method that returns a promise to an object.

Comment: @NikhilVJ Would you mind posting an equivalent ajax-only response ?

Answer (score 32):

The `.json` method returns a promise, not the parsed value itself. If you want to access both the response and the parsed value in the same callback, you'll need to use nested functions like this:

```
fetch(url).then(response => {
    response.json().then(parsedValue => {
        // code that can access both here
    })
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `await` inside an asynchronous function to eliminate the need for callbacks.

```
const response = await fetch(url);
const parsedValue = await response.json();

// code that can access both here
```

Of course, you'll want to check for errors, either with a `.catch(...)` call on a Promise or with a `try...catch` block in an `async` function. You could make a function that handles JSON and error cases, and then reuse it for all fetches. For example, something like this:

```
function handle(response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then(parsedValue => {
            // the status was ok and the body could be parsed
            return { response, parsedValue };
        }).catch(err => {
            // the status was ok but the body was empty or not JSON
            return { response };
        });

    } else {
        return response.json().catch(err => {
            // the status was not ok and the body was not JSON
            throw new Error(response.statusText);
        }).then(parsedValue => {
            // the status was not ok and the body was JSON
            throw new Error(parsedValue.error); // assuming our API returns an object with an error property
        });
    }
}
```

I don't think it's the best design pattern, but hopefully this clarifies how the fetch API works. Note that the call to `fetch` itself can throw an error if something prevents the request from being sent in the first place.

PS: I avoided naming any variable or property `json` since that is the name of the text format. Once it's been parsed, it is no longer JSON. You might want to use a more meaningful name than `parsedValue`.

Comment: Note: I have used a solution like this in production once, but it was for a small app calling a backend API I made myself. There are probably better patterns to follow if your use case isn't trivial.

Comment: Interesting patterns can be found here: https://danlevy.net/you-may-not-need-axios/

Answer (score 15):

Using two 'then's seem unnecessary to me.

async/await could get the job done pretty easily.

```
    fetch('http://test.com/getData')
      .then( async (response) => {

        // get json response here
        let data = await response.json();
        
        if(data.status === 200){
         // Process data here
        }else{
         // Rest of status codes (400,500,303), can be handled here appropriately
        }

      })
      .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
      })
```

Comment: I wouldn't mix async/await syntax with `.then(...)` syntax. If you're going to use `await` at all, then you should probably use `const response = await fetch(...);` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The introduction of [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) makes it easy to handle data from dependant promises in one place.

Since it doesn't involve the use of callback functions, the variables all exist in the same scope.

```js
const myFunction = async (url) => {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const status = response.status;
    const data = await response.json();
    return { data, status };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
return fetch(url)
    .then((r)=> {return {response: r.json(), status: r.status}})
```

Comment: I've tried. The problem is that r.json() is a promise and returning it like this means I get a promise in the response field.

Comment: than @Suren Srapyan is best solution I think

Comment: This will produce an object where `response` is a promise.